# Parse content of json in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, typescript, parsing

I've a response JSON which i would like to parse. Specifically, I am interested in visualizing in an HTML the values contained in the "raw".
Below is an example of the JSON file.

```
{
   "values":{
      "first":{
         "raw":"first value",
         "encoded":"1019570973946118"
      },
      "second":{
         "raw":"second value",
         "encoded":"1822871964691"
      }
   }
}
```

Using `JSON.stringify` I can see the entire JSON but, of course that is not my intention.

Thank you

Edit:

I'm sorry, I was very superficial in my initial description. I would like to extract the value contained in raw of this example json file and display it in a react component in HTML. Something like: `{JSON.stringify(raw)}`

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. The json seems to already be parsed

Comment: What is your intention?

Comment: Are you looking to take a JSON string and extract an array of values from all the fields called `raw`, then display it in a react component?

Comment: I'm sorry guys, i made an updated. Unfortunately i'm not allowed to update the repo or the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a JSON string to an actual javascript object is NOT done by `JSON.stringify()` but by `JSON.parse()`.

So in order to retrieve the `raw` part you would have to do this:

```js
const response = `{
   "values":{
      "first":{
         "raw":"first value",
         "encoded":"1019570973946118"
      },
      "second":{
         "raw":"second value",
         "encoded":"1822871964691"
      }
   }
}`;

const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(response)

for (const key of parsedJSON.values.keys()) {
   const raw = parsedJSON.values[key].raw;
   console.log(raw)
}
```

The variable `raw` could be used as a prop, state, etc. now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe some infos: i'm getting the JSON from "outside", it gets first decoded from a support class and then the only thing i would like to do is display in a HTML the 2 parameters (first and second value). So the for loop is actually not it.